# Convergence of series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{1}{n^{3}} $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

**Problem:**

I am trying to prove that series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{1}{n^{3}}$$ converges.

**My attempt:**

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|\sin\frac{1}{n^{3}}| \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}$$.  Then $\sum b_n = \sum 1/n^3$ is convergent $p$ series, where $p = 3$. Hence by comparison test given series in the question converges.

or

If $a_n = \sin \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $b_n = 1/n^3%$ then $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$, as $n \rightarrow\infty$. Hence by the limit comparison test both the series converges.

Am I on the right path to solve this question?, or are there alternative approaches to address this problem? Thank you for your assistance.

Thanking you

Comment: Both of these are good options for answering the question, and both solutions look good to me.

Comment: Did you forget the sum-sign on the right side ? Apart from this , the solution is correct.

Comment: @Peter I forgot that. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions are okay, but you can also use the Taylor approximation of the sine function: $\sin x\sim x $ when $x\to 0$.
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{1}{n^{3}}\sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$
and the last series converges since $3>1$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.